# Perform Assert.AreMatch() to deep compare properties in two objects

Tags: c#, testing, memcached, assertions

I am writing tests against our Caching mechanism and I want to be sure that what goes into the cache is the same as what comes out, ie that all properties match. Here is a fictional example of how I would like it to work

```
    [Test]
    public void add_client_model_member_to_cache_then_retreve()
    {
        //arrange
        MemcachedClient client = new MemcachedClient();
        Member member = GetMember();
        client.Store(StoreMode.Set, "membertest", member);

        // act
        var result = client.Get<Member>("membertest");

        // assert
        Assert.AreMatch(result, member);
    }
```

It is not feasible to perform Assert.AreEqual on each property as there will be many of these tests with many properties in each.

Wow, thanks Jon. I think you answered that in under one minute. Here are my resulting solution for any interested parties. I implemented as Jon suggested (I think) however I got into a little trouble with array properties and as such my solution only handles arrays of ints (all I currently require).

It also got to be a fairly slippery slope if I try to check deeper than one level. I am sure this can be achieved however for my purposes it is not required.

```
private bool AreMatch(object initial, object result)
    {
        if (initial.Equals(result)) 
            return true;

        foreach (var property in initial.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            var initialPropValue = property.GetValue(initial,null);
            var resultPropValue = result.GetType().GetProperty(property.Name).GetValue(result,null);

            if (property.PropertyType.IsArray)
            {
                if ((initialPropValue != null && resultPropValue != null) && !Enumerable.SequenceEqual((int[])initialPropValue, (int[])resultPropValue))
                        return false;                   
            }
            else if (!object.Equals(initialPropValue, resultPropValue))
            {
                return false;
            }
            else if (initialPropValue != null && property.PropertyType.IsClass)
            {
                // Don't go deeper than one level, this got me into trouble
                //if (!AreMatch(initialPropValue, resultPropValue))
                //  return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

The method above can be used in the following situations

```
    [Test]
    public void cached_result_is_same_as_original()
    {
        //arrange
        Member member = GetMember();
        client.Store(StoreMode.Set, "membertest", member);

        // act
        var result = client.Get<Member>("membertest");

        // assert
        Assert.IsTrue(AreMatch(member, result));
    }

    [Test]
    public void cached_result_is_same_as_original()
    {
        //arrange
        Member member = GetMember();
        client.Store(StoreMode.Set, "membertest", member);

        // act
        var result = client.Get<Member>("membertest");
        result.FirstName = "Result is different"; 

        // assert
        Assert.IsFalse(AreMatch(member, result));
    }
```

Comment: I appended the solution I used to the question(see above).. it could be added to for multi-level property traversal support, but this was not required and can get pretty messy fairly quickly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you could certainly write something to recurse through all the properties, and call `object.Equals` on the result of fetching the property value from the expected and actual ones. Use `Type.GetProperties()` to get the properties themselves, and `PropertyInfo.GetValue` to get the value.

It'll be somewhat crude, but you could always tweak it if necessary.